# Error after starting Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, runtime-error

Every time I start windows 7,I get the following error:

[image]

What is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Get rid of a terrible AV, for one.  Instead, use [MSE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download).

Comment: This site isn't a good place for recommendations, but I would point out that MSSE has some serious blind spots which have dramatically reduced its fitness over the last year and a half.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yep, I recently read a story about MSSE, which seriously put me off recommending it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vprot.exe is associated with the `AVG Security Toolbar`. Go into your Control Panel and remove `AVG Security Bar` or `AVG Technologies.`

If that doesn't work you'll have to uninstall and re-install `AVG.`

Comment: speaking about toolbars how can i remove `conduit engine`? uninstall via control panel doesn't remove it

Comment: Try and find the directory location and check if it has an uninstaller. If it does, run it as an Admin.